# How to open a new form from another project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, resources, preferences

In my soloution I have created some projects and one of them is the main project so it gets fired up when application starts.

I want to use only this main project's Properties file to store all Properties (string, objects and etc..) so for this case I have to reference this main form project in other form projects (Hope I am making sense!)

Now the problem is when I want to call one of those forms inside my main form projects, because I can not reference to them (I get this circular dependency warning), I am unable to do so! What can be the workearound in this case?

Comment: I think it would make more sense to put all of the resource files in their own DLL.  You would avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: My idea is to later create a form so users can modify this resources. is this a bad idea?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that.  Resources are compile-time, unless you are linking to external files, such as images or text files.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only link in one direction. You must think of a project as a upside down tree. You can reference a parent class, but the parent class can't reference the children class. So if you need a feature that is needed in both, move it to the parent of the two classes, or move it to a 3rd class, and both reference it.

Answer (score 0):

you pass main form instance as constructor argument when you call one of those forms in the main.  In that way you access properties of main project. main form has to be precedent to others.  the other way wouldnt work unless you put all properties as independent class or construct